# how does elasticsearch select destination node in shard movement?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a large ES cluster. I generally get disk alert since we have a disk alert policy set to 90% [my ES high watermark is set to 87%].  When I look at shard allocation I see the nodes moving out from high disk usage node to some random node, which resolves my disk issue quickly but it generally won't move that shard to a node which has lowest disk usage. Is it possible to force elasticsearch move shard to a node which has lowest disk usage instead of moving it to a random node when the high watermark is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ES does not use random decision it takes into account [a lot of factors](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/ClusterModule.java#L183):

- MaxRetryAllocationDecider - prevents shards from being allocated on
  any node if the shards allocation has been retried N times without
  success
- NodeVersionAllocationDecider - prevents relocation or allocation from nodes that might not be
  version compatible.
- SameShardAllocationDecider - prevents multiple instances of the same shard to be allocated on the same node.
- DiskThresholdDecider - checks that the node a shard is potentially being allocated to has enough disk space.
- ShardsLimitAllocationDecider - limits the number of shards per node on a per index or node-wide basis.
- AwarenessAllocationDecider - controls shard allocation based on awareness key-value pairs defined in the node configuration.

As you can see there are a lot of factors and there is no low disc space checkers. So the only solution is to write [your own plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.6/plugin-authors.html) which extends `org.elasticsearch.plugins.ClusterPlugin` which will provide your decider. But  I think this is not a good idea because it contradicts the main design/idea of ES allocation decider pattern:

- any decider can veto decisions of all previous deciders
- any positive solution has no influence on the subsequent decision
- most of the deciders use local node data

This strategy allows you to prohibit and is designed to maximize the freedom to choose within a cluster. That's why from the outside it looks like a randomly moving. This is a great strategy for large and long-lived clusters.

The introduction of any kind of biasing may leads to catastrophic problems in production. Let's imagine you have disc space based decider and one server has incredibly large HDD - after a while all shards will be allocated on this machine. To solve this problem, it is necessary to take into account more significant resources like CPU, Memory, Network, amount of shards etc. Moreover, we need to come up with a metric and weights for each factor.